# How to fill in values in a crosstab (SQLlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, crosstab

Hi I am having some problems filling up cross-tabs in SQLite. I am only able to create headers but not able to fill in the values in it. I have been looking for ways but not able to find anything so far. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CPW7J4V0RVrmwfR4Opnz-z7BUpdOTJYR/view?usp=sharing

```
CREATE VIEW avg_salary AS  
SELECT team, season, avg(salary) as avg_salary
FROM pergame
GROUP BY team, season;

CREATE VIEW crstab_avg_salary AS
SELECT team AS 'team',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2007-08 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2007-08',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2008-09 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2008-09',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2009-10 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2009-10',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2010-11 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2010-11',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2011-12 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2011-12',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2012-13 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2012-13',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2013-14 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2013-14',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2014-15 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2014-15',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2015-16 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2015-16',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = 2016-17 THEN avg_salary END) AS '2016-17'
FROM avg_salary
GROUP BY team;

.mode csv
.output q4c1.csv
SELECT * FROM crstab_avg_salary;
.output stdout
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4sS5.jpg)

Comment: I'd start by quoting the season in the WHEN clause: season = '2007-08'

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate a little? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT team AS 'team',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2007-08' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2007-08',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2008-09' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2008-09',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2009-10' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2009-10',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2010-11' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2010-11',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2011-12' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2011-12',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2012-13' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2012-13',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2013-14' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2013-14',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2014-15' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2014-15',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2015-16' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2015-16',
AVG(CASE WHEN season = '2016-17' THEN avg_salary END) AS '2016-17'
FROM avg_salary
GROUP BY team;
```

The change is just that I quoted the seasons in the `WHEN` clause of the `CASE` expression. E.g. 2007-08 (read 2007 minus 08) gives 1999, for which you don't have data in your data set.

Comment: Thanks I get it now!